# Reclass Using Field Calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to reclass 3000, 2000, 1000 and 0.5 into 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively in a new field using field calculator. However it keeps returning an error message and I can't figure out why, any ideas?

```
def Reclass( !BUFF_DIST! ):
    if !BUFF_DIST! = 3000:
        return 1
    else if (!BUFF_DIST!) = 2000:
        return 2
    else if (!BUFF_DIST!) = 2000:
        return 3
    else: 
        return 4
```

Comment: (4000-v)/1000 will yield correct result on integer field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python parser and call the function with the actual field name enclosed in !!. BUFF_DIST=

```
Reclass(!BUFF_DIST!)
```

When you define the function use whatever name you want, for example buffdist. Also change = to == and else if to elif. Pre-Logic script code:

```
def Reclass( buffdist ):
    if buffdist == 3000:
        return 1
    elif buffdist == 2000:
        return 2
    elif buffdist == 1000:
        return 3
    else: 
        return 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've just tried it and it still returns an error message. Just to clarify I've put that into a Python Praser with the type set as Number with no codeblock.

Comment: You need the code block

Comment: That's worked now thank you! From there i'm trying to convert that into a raster in order to input it into model. However when i convert the polygon file to raster with the field being risk, it only returns one value for the whole raster instead of the 4 separate values. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Nice accept my answer with the checkbox please. Post a new question for that