# NULL value not equal to empty value for attribute

Tags: arcmap, query, select-by-attribute, expression

I have a `feature layer` in a `gdb`. It has an attribute named `uniqueid`. Some of rows have a value for `uniqueid` and some do not. I am trying to select only the features that have a value (are not blank).

[image]

Using the `Select by Attributes` dialog box, I am trying to create an expression that will weed out the blank features. I tried using `where: unique IS NOT NULL` but that selected everything, both the features with a value and those that were blank. I then tried using `Get Unique Values` and chose '', which was one of the options. It through an error. What am I doing wrong here? How can I select just the features that have a value for the `uniqueid` attribute field?

[image]

Here's the actual text version of the error as requested:

> There was a problem selecting
>
> An invalid SQL statement was used. An invalid SQL statement was
>   used.[fottprint_cslf_union_20181004] An invalid SQL statement was
>   used.[SELECT OBJECTID FROM footprint_cslf_union_20181004 WHERE
>   uniqueid IS NOT '']

Comment: Have you tried uniqueid <> '' ?

Comment: Yes. I got the same error as above.

Comment: Can you post the error when you try uniquid <> ''.  Make sure it's 2 single quotes, not a double quote.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the error in ASCII text this makes the error message legible on all devices and permits free text search. I'm not aware of any language that would accept `*column* IS NOT ''`. Part of your issue may be that `UNIQUE` is a reserved word in SQL, so there may be an alias to an actual column name `unique_`.

Comment: Added text version of the error as requested. How can I determine if the shown column name is an alias and get the actual column name?

Comment: Do all unique ids have a common part of the string (eg. CA..)? If so, you could try to use the  LIKE operator of SQL.

Comment: Another alternative you could try is to create a new column and use the ‘Field Calculator’ to write a python script that reclasses the values based on the ‘uniqueid’ column, as shown here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266620/reclass-using-field-calculator-in-arcmap . Afterwards you can ‘select by Attribute’ through your new column.

Comment: No. The id is created from the state. So CA is Cali, GA would be Georgia, etc... I tried that and it worked but then realized that it would be too verbose to add every state in. I may be able to add a abbreviated state name list and do it in Python like `if(uniqueid in stateList: arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(...)` or something but I just thought that 'IS NOT NULL' would be more efficient.

Comment: What if you used a "Select by Attributes" similar to "uniqueid LIKE '%CA%'" or  "uniqueid LIKE '%0%'"

Comment: See the above comment. I tried just using `LIKE '%'` I'll try `"uniqueid LIKE '%0%'"`. That might produce better results.

Comment: Do you have to use the uniqueid field? I see in your example the [...ET_FID] field is 0...is this the same / unique for all the uniqueid fields? Could you use this as a "Select by Attributes" statement instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IS NOT syntax can only be used with null but you have a '' (an empty string value delimited by quote) so the correct syntax should be `uniqueid <> ''`

I think this is because your field is a text field where null/none/empty value are stored as empty string (thus the '' in the value selector), in a numeric field you get "real" null value and could use the `uniqueid IS NOT null` syntax

Comment: OK, this turned out to be the correct answer. For whatever reason, `uniqueid <> ''` did not work originally. Maybe I was adding a space in the quotes. Whatever the reason, I shot down arcMap and restarted and it magically worked. I popped the same statement in a `arcpy.selectByAttribute_management(...)` function and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the Wildcard "%" to Select By Attributes.

By using the Wildcard to form a statement that should contain characters that all the attributes should have you can select the Attributes that are not ''.

The syntax would be:

```
uniqueid LIKE '%CA%'
```

Or if CA is not common to all the attributes, try a numerical attribute value:

```
uniqueid LIKE '%0%'
```

You may need to string a few of these together to cover all your bases / potential combinations:

```
uniqueid LIKE '%0%' OR uniqueid LIKE '%1%' OR uniqueid LIKE '%CA%'
```

Depending on the values in the uniqueid field.